# Position element to the bottom of a height: 100% div

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I would like to "pin" a button to the bottom of a sidebar-div that has a height of 100%, as it should fill the whole left side of the page.

I tried to do it this way:

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
 }
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  top: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

It might be because of the height in percent, as it works with a Pixel-height, but there must be some way of getting this done with percent, as the sidebar must span the entire page height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, give your `html` and `body` a height of 100% as follows. Right now they don't have a defined height set (so they are 0px high), so your button is *technically* already at the bottom.

**Live Example:**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
 }
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am marking your comment as correct, as it indeed is the solution to the problem. However, I had that solution implemented already. The problem was that a Bootstrap-Navbar i used "pushed" the whole page 51px down, Therefore pushing the "bottom:0"-button out of view. Using "bottom: 51px" solved it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your container doesn't have any actual height. You'll need to define the height on both your html and body tags too to use percent height there.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```